# Equation of the Surface of Fusée Barrel

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

The *fusée* is a device used in certain mainspring-driven clocks, to level-out the torque that the mainspring applies to the movement. A mainspring *without* correction produces a torque that declines roughly linearly with the angle through which it has unwound. Although the *very purpose* of a clock's movement is to produce rotation at a rate *independent* of the magnitude of the applied torque, there is still a *second-order* error: the greater swing of the balance-wheel, or pendulum, or whatever the regulating mechanism is, is not *perfectly* offset by the increased *speed* of the motion; and a clock can be made more accurate by installing some kind of mechanism that in some way *levels out* the driving torque.

Anyway the *fusée* is a mechanism for doing *precisely that*; and consists of a ... not *cone* ... I don't know what the name for it *is* ... a concave *quasi* -cone with a quasi-helickal track of gear teeth on it. A chain - somewhat like a bicycle chain (but usually much finer) - is wound onto it and the barrel of the mainspring in such a way that when the mainspring is fully-wound it is pulling at the fusée barrel at the *narrowest* part; and as the mainspring unwinds, the chain also *winds off* the fusée barrel in such a way that the radius of the point on that barrel at which it is pulling is always such as to compensate for the diminution of the torque of the mainspring. A good book on *horology* (such as *Grimshaw's* classic treatise - probably *the definitive* horological text) will probably have a thorough description of this device, with diagrams & all.

The question is - assuming the torque of the mainspring *does* decrease linearly with angle-through-which-it-has-turned, what is the equation giving the *radius* of the track on the barrel as a function of angle about *it's* axis?

Or might it be easier to formulate it as a function of unwinding angle of the mainspring? I think *probably not* ... but if someone can show that the other formulation has a great advantage, I would be extremely interested. But I doubt there is ... infact it's essentially just introducing *distance **along*** the track as a variable and getting the equation in terms of that instead. Actually, it's *undoubtedly* easier - but to *construct* one we need $r$ in terms of $\theta$ (or *vice versa*) explicitly, really.

They have other applications also - I have read that some high-grade *crossbows* have them, for easing the arming of them.

[image: Schematic Diagram of Entire Mechanism]

[image: Photograph of Barrel Alone]

So, referring now to these pictures: what would be the equation of $r$ in terms of $\theta$ polar co-ordinates along the track on the surface of these barrels?

As can see also, it doesn't absolutely *have* to be a chain & betoothen track - a cable & smooth track works also.

Comment: A little figure would be useful...

Comment: It would - I agree. How do you incorporate them on here?

Comment: Click on the 4th icon you have at the top of the edit window, which looks like a mountain with two summits. A window opens ; you need to drag the figure you want to attach into this window ; then click at the bottom left on the button "add picture" . Take care :  the figure will be included where you have left your cursor.

Comment: Right - thanks mightily ... I'll look into that.

Comment: I _might_ have done it ... but I got a load of "... visible to you.only until peer-reviewed". I'll have to be a _tad patient_ with this!

Comment: I've actually _got_ a solution to this now ... but I don't know whether it would really be in accordance with the _manners_ of this forum to post it, as then there would no-longer really be a question! But I am _positively itching_ to post it ... and it _has turned out_ to be about _as_ interesting as I thought it would.

Comment: Ambrette: Self-answers are welcome. (But perhaps relax with the italics a little---they're used so much here that they cease to convey the emphasis desired, I think.)

Comment: I advise you to post it at the bottom of your question beginning with a title as the first sentence of your last remark : "Actually, I have got a solution that I would like to share with you", or something like that...

Comment: All that said, I find the original question a bit confusingly worded: For example, the question reads, "...and as the mainspring unwinds, the chain also winds off the fusée barrel...", but from the illustration it appears that as the cable unwinds from the main spring, it should wind (not "unwind"---if that's what "winds off" means) around the fusée.

Comment: The configuration I had in mind was the chain being wound _on_ the fusée barrel all the way from one end to the other - and it starts with the mainspring fully wound in _its_ cylinder (a plain cylinder), and it's pulling initially at the narrow end of the fusée barrel - that is the scenario in my analysis ... perhaps you are thinking of the scenario of the mainspring inside the fusée barrel.

Comment: Either setup is valid, & I think both have been used. And when I say 'inside' I ought just to have said on the same axis ... but anyway - the fusée barrel can be either the driven or the driving ... and in the former case the chain will wind off, & in the latter wind on.

Answer (score 1):

As seems to be happening regularly, the thought that goes into framing the question for presentation to an audience goes also towards clarifying it! So the solution has come to me more quickly than I at first thought it would. It also brought the pleasant surprise that a certain integral that looked intractable turned out to be actually quite tractable.

Set $l_0$ = the length displaced at the point at which the force of the mainspring falls to 0, & $r_0$ = the *minimum* radius of the track on the fusée barrel, ie its radius at commencement of unwinding of the mainspring, & $F_0$ = initial tension in the chain or cable.

$$k(l_0 - l)=\frac{F_0 r_0}{r}  .$$

Because $k=F_0/l_0$

$$l_0 - l=\frac{l_0 r_0}{r}  .$$

Set $a=\sqrt{l_0 r_0}$

$$\frac{dl}{dr}=\frac{a^2}{r^2}$$

$$\frac{dl}{d\theta}=\frac{a^2}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}$$

$$\sqrt{r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2}=\frac{a^2}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}$$

$$r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2=\frac{a^4}{r^4}(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2$$

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\frac{r}{\sqrt{\frac{a^4}{r^4}-1}}$$

$$\int_{r_0}^r\sqrt{\frac{a^4}{r^4}-1}\frac{dr}{r}=\int_{\theta_0}^\theta d\theta$$

The integral in $r$ is, perhaps surprisingly (it was to me anyway), actually quite tractable - it's actually just a scaled & transformed case of

$$\int\sqrt{e^x-1}dx =2(\sqrt{e^x-1} -\arctan\sqrt{e^x-1}). $$

Set $\theta_0=\frac{l_0}{r_0}$.

$$\theta=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\theta_0^2-1}-\arctan\sqrt{\theta_0^2-1}-(\sqrt{\frac{a^4}{r^4}-1}-\arctan\sqrt{\frac{a^4}{r^4}-1})$$

So the problem can be *dedimensionalised* by setting a characteristic angle

$$\theta_0=\frac{l_0}{r_0}$$

& characteristic length

$$\sqrt{l_0 r_0} .$$

Set $\rho=r/a$, whence the initial value of $\rho$ is $1/\sqrt \theta_0$.

If $r$ is only varying slowly *wrt* $\theta$, ie at the narrow end of the barrel, we have simply

$$\theta = \int_{1/\sqrt{\theta_0}}^\rho\frac{d\rho}{\rho^3}=\frac{1}{2}(\theta_0-\frac{1}{\rho^2}) .$$

*Not* making that simplifying assumption, we have

$$\theta=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\theta_0^2-1}-\arctan\sqrt{\theta_0^2-1}-(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\rho^4}-1}-\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1}{\rho^4}-1}) .$$

It's notable that in the approximate solution $\rho$ can increase without limit, whereas in the accurate one it cannot exceed unity. If we set $\rho=1-\epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ <<1), and also $\sqrt{\theta_0^2-1}-\arctan\sqrt{\theta_0^2-1}=\Theta_0$, then when $\rho$ is nearly 1

$$\theta≈\frac{\Theta_0}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(2\sqrt\epsilon-(2\sqrt\epsilon-\frac{8\epsilon^{3/2}}{3}))$$

$$\theta≈\frac{\Theta_0}{2}-\frac{4\epsilon^{3/2}}{3} ,$$

so we have an abrupt termination of order 3/2 in the growth of $\theta$ at $\rho=1$ ... ie $r=a$.

The total amount of chain or cable that becomes unwound is

$$a\int_{1/\sqrt\theta_0}^1\frac{d\rho}{\rho^2}=a(\sqrt\theta_0-1) = l_0-a .$$

The amount of the total length $l_0$ left unutilised, then, is $a$, whence the torque is a fraction

$$\frac{a}{l_0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt\theta_0}$$

of its initial value; however the radius on the fusée barrel at which this force is now applied is multiplied by the factor

$$\frac{a}{r_0}=\sqrt\theta_0 ... $$

so the torque is the same at the end as at the beginning.

It's notable that the function (in the exact solution) expressing  $\theta$ in terms of $r$ cannot be inverted in closed-form to give $r$ in terms of $\theta$. But this doesn't really matter, as the function the *way-round* that it is is just as suitable for actually  designing one of these things on a drawing-board.

Looking at this solution qualitatively it can be seen how when $r$ is only slightly greater than $r_0$, the exact solution cleaves closely to the approximate one ... although does not quite tend asymptotically to it, as $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ does not tend to zero at $r_0$. As $r\rightarrow a$, however, the particular *shape* of the exact solution *kicks-in*, with the $\sqrt(a^4/r^4-1)$ 'rescuing' it from the clearly absurd behaviour of $\theta$ tending to a finite value as $r$ increases abundantly, and the $\arctan$ providing for an intuitively realistic $\epsilon^{3/2}$ termination, rather than the absurd $\epsilon^{1/2}$ one that it would have without the $\arctan$ or something similar to cancel the first order term in $\epsilon$.

When I say 'exact' solution, there are still actually one or two troublesome matters that have been neglected in my analysis. One is the shift in the chain in the *axial* direction as it winds/unwinds. I decided that as the shift can easily be set up to be the same on both barrels (indeed, it would be only natural to do so), it would probably only affect the total length of chain used - it would need to be longer by ~$z_0^2/2l_0$, where $z_0$ is the total axial displacement, ie the *length* of each barrel (presumed equal). The other is that the chain makes a changing angle to the to the line joining the centres of the barrels ... but I do think that effect is probably negligible. If anyone wishes to present a solution that incorporates these effects ... be my guest! But I would be *truly* amazed if you could *still* get a closed-form elementary-function solution. I was surprised enough to find that mine was such, *as it stands*!